# How to get Dynamic Variable value In Test Class

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce, exception

I have Two VF pages (SME Coach, SME info). SME Coach have a Picklist field. 
When I choose One Value here It will Dynamically Updated in Another picklist field (SME) In SME Info.
Using the Value of SME In SME Info I query some Records In class and do others process.
This Code is Working well in  Class. My Problem is, How to get the Value of SME field in Test class.

Note : SME picklist exists only in Visualforce Page and I did not create field in SMEobject to store value for it.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardcontroller="SME_Coaching__c" extensions="smecoachingcontroller" >
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageblock >
   <apex:selectlist label="SMEvalue" value="{!SMEselected}"  styleClass="dropdown_large" required="true" size="1" id="enableSMEList">                 
    <apex:selectoptions value="{!SMENames}"/>
    </apex:selectlist>
  <apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Query In class :

```
test1= [select id,Name__c from Our_SME__c where id =:SMEselected];
```

//Need to get SMEselected value in TestClass 
//Woking Well in Class.

Test Class :

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class testSMECoachingcls {
    public static testmethod void m1() {
        Our_VA__c ova = new Our_VA__c();
        ova.First_Name__c = 'Ksamy';
        ova.Last_Name__c = 'madasamy';
        insert ova;
        our_sme__C sme = new our_sme__C();
        sme.First_Name__c = 'm';
        sme.last_name__C = 'm';
        sme.Is_available__c  = TRUE;
        insert sme;
        sme_coaching__C smec = new sme_coaching__C();
        smec.Skills_Catagory__c='TC (Offers, HUD, Opening - Closing)';
        smec.sme1__c='Lorie Landayan';
        smec.New_Our_VA__c = ova.id;
        smec.Our_SME__c = sme.id;
        smec.selected_SME__c='m m';
        smec.Start_date__c = system.today();
        smec.status__c = 'completed';
        insert smec;
        ApexPages.standardcontroller c = new ApexPages.standardcontroller(smec);
        smecoachingcontroller obj = new smecoachingcontroller(c);
        obj.getSMENameItems();
        obj.availability();
        obj.goback();
        obj.cancelcheckpage();
        obj.getAcctNameItems();
        obj.recordsave();
        obj.savennew();
        obj.cancel();
    }
}
```

at invocation of `obj.goback()` occurred the following error:

> Error MessageSystem.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Comment: Without the code from the `smecoachingcontroller` class it is impossible to help. Can you edit your question and add the constructor and at least the `goback` method code?

Comment: Side note, this is not a good test as there is no use of `System.assert`, `System.assertEquals`, or `System.assertNotEquals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working backward from your query, the act populating the SMESelected value should be fairly straightforward.

without having the code of the controller class itself, it is difficult to know for certain, but working backward from this query:

```
test1= [select id,Name__c from Our_SME__c where id =:SMEselected];
```

If the error you report is in fact related to the unsuccessful retrieving of a record from this query into the variable `test1`, then what you need is some code in your controller setup in the test that populates `SMEselected`.

So at some point after this line:

```
smecoachingcontroller obj = new smecoachingcontroller(c);
```

You would do something like;

```
obj.SMEselected = anIdVar; //ostensibly you've created, this id value earlier as well
```